# Setting a null values to TeeChart using Javascript

Tags: javascript, teechart

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Steema.TeeChart.Chart ch1 = WebChart1.Chart;
        Line fastLine1 = new Line();
        WebChart1.Chart.Series.Add(fastLine1);
        double[] yValues = {1,4,5,2,23,63,33,20,0,77,94,65,45,23};
        fastLine1.Add(yValues);

        fastLine1.SetNull(0);
        fastLine1.SetNull(1);
        fastLine1.SetNull(3);

        // (WebChart1.Chart.Series[0] as Line).TreatNulls = TreatNullsStyle.DoNotPaint;

        string[] customCode = new string[] {
                WebChart1.ClientID + "_chart.series.items[0].format.stroke.size = 3;",
                WebChart1.ClientID + "_chart.series.items[0].format.shadow.visible = false;",
                WebChart1.ClientID + "_chart.title.visible=true;",
                WebChart1.ClientID + "_chart.series.items[0].treatNulls = \"dontPaint\";"};
    }
```

With this small example of code i am trying to demonstrate how to work with adding null values to Series. With using HTML5 I had no problems with showing "gaps" between two points in linechart.

```
<tchart:WebChart id="WebChart1" style="Z-INDEX: 107; LEFT: 24px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 60px" runat="server" ..... PictureFormat="JScript"></tchart:WebChart>
```

When parameter PictureFormat is "PNG", example is working as it should be, but with changing value to "JScript" I was not able to reproduce the same result.

I tried changing transparent colors for this points, different ways of adding values to series but none these of attempts was successful.

Is there any solution with using JavaScript? I have TeeChartNET 4.1.2015 version.

Thanks for you help

Peter